# Error H10 when deploying Sinatra app to Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, deployment, sinatra, httparty

I cannot get my app to deploy to Heroku. So frustrating.

Here is the repository: [repository link](http://www.github.com/johnsalzarulo/gifinder)

Things I have tried:

- I have updated my config.ru with everything I need per the heroku deployment page found [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack)
- I have run `heroku run rake db:migrate`
- I have run `heroku restart`
- I have ensured I have an updated gemfile
- I double checked that I have the 'require' statements in my app.rb

**Any thoughts? My error logs I am getting are below:**

```
2014-11-02T03:46:07.404128+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy bbe19c1 by johnsalzarulo@gmail.com
2014-11-02T03:46:07.404202+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v17 created by johnsalzarulo@gmail.com
2014-11-02T03:46:08.439283+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-11-02T03:46:11.353727+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 43798`
2014-11-02T03:46:13.210413+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2014-11-02T03:46:13.210411+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2014-11-02T03:46:13.210388+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config.ru:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./gifinder (LoadError)
2014-11-02T03:46:13.210410+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:1:in `block in <main>'
2014-11-02T03:46:13.210424+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2014-11-02T03:46:13.210425+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2014-11-02T03:46:13.210414+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-11-02T03:46:13.210415+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-11-02T03:46:13.210417+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2014-11-02T03:46:13.210419+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-11-02T03:46:13.210418+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2014-11-02T03:46:13.210421+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2014-11-02T03:46:13.210427+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
2014-11-02T03:46:13.210430+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:141:in `start'
2014-11-02T03:46:13.210432+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
2014-11-02T03:46:13.210434+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
2014-11-02T03:46:13.210437+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
2014-11-02T03:46:13.977897+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-11-02T03:46:13.970947+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-11-02T03:46:15.252296+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gifinder.herokuapp.com request_id=7106f663-fa15-4c74-ab8e-f5df75030a55 fwd="174.129.111.111" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-11-02T03:46:42.265175+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gifinder.herokuapp.com request_id=900cbb04-7ee9-4392-9f2f-7d4e833b15c0 fwd="24.43.108.83" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-11-02T03:46:43.407062+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gifinder.herokuapp.com request_id=ce46eed0-4a7f-4633-81ec-c826a3c90e30 fwd="24.43.108.83" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 3):

Your config.ru file is trying to load a non-existent file with the require statement. Change this line  `require './gifinder'` to:

```
require './app'
```

or, change the filename of `app.rb` to `gifinder.rb`. You should also follow iain's advice and remove the double Gemfile.lock because that's bound to cause problems.

Your require for HTTParty should also be lowercase. I fetched your repo and got it work on heroku by changing the require to all lowercase:

```
require 'httparty'
```

Comment: Fetched your repo and got it working by updating the require for HTTParty. Post updated with what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you've done it, but you have two `Gemfile.lock`s. I'd remove them both and re-run Bundler, and `git rm` the one that shouldn't be there.

Also note that Heroku now uses procfiles more extensively than previously, so get hold of Foreman and [define a procfile](http://blog.kuntz.co/2014/03/15/deploying-a-sinatra-app-to-heroku.html#the-procfile).

---

In addition, when I run `bundle install --binstubs --path=vendor` I get this message:

> Post-install message from heroku:  !    The `heroku` gem has been
>   deprecated and replaced with the Heroku Toolbelt.  !    Download and
>   install from: https://toolbelt.heroku.com  !    For API access, see:
>   https://github.com/heroku/heroku.rb

so remove `gem 'heroku', '~> 3.15.0'` from the Gemfile and `require 'heroku'` (which was never needed in the app anyway) from app.rb. When I do that, the command `bin/rackup config.ru` runs the app for me on localhost:9292 just fine.

Comment: @JohnSalzarulo I've updated the answer with what worked for me.

Comment: Looks Like I was also having this problem as well. Not sure how that happened. Thanks.